# Show Author and Time Error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have this method on the article page which show the article author and timestamp and it works fine in view/articles/show.html.erb. But when I put the same method on the index page under /views/articles/_article.html.erb I keep getting this error - it works in one page display but not the other. Any suggestions?

'The error:'

```
NoMethodError in Articles#index

Showing /Users/blog/app/views/articles/_article.html.erb where line #13 raised:

undefined method `User' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #13):

11:
12: <div class="post_by">
13: Posted by <%= @article.user.'username' %> on <%= @article.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %> 
14: </div>
15: 
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/articles/index.html.erb

Rails.root: /Users/blog

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/articles/_article.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_articles__article_html_erb__997953145_2197490260_6874828'
app/views/articles/index.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_articles_index_html_erb___514612748_2197511860_0'
app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:11:in `index'
```

Comment: `@article` is not defined. I expect `@articles` is though, and your partial expects the instance variable rather than a local variable. Can see the code for the articles partial, the index page, and the controller?

Comment: It won't let me post the code you requested as a newbie :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's expecting an @article object to be present, and you're probably not initializing one in your index method. For example, "show" defines it:

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
```

But make sure your index method also has something similar, if indeed you need an article object to be loaded

```
def index
  @articles = Article.all
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
```

Now, I don't know what your goal is with the index page, but you would have pass in a specific ID from somewhere in order to load the article object in "index". Therefore, this is a somewhat contrived example.

A common use case to instantiate an object in your "index" method would be if you have the "New Article" form on the index page itself and it needed an empty Article object to work off of. E.g.:

```
def index
  @articles = Article.all
  @article = Article.new
end
```

Comment: How is instantiating a new @article in the index going to solve the problem of @article.user.username? The user is most likely already got @articles correct. They're using the render collection using partials which negates the declaration of a useless and expensive instance variable @article since Rails automatically give you the object from the array of @articles automatically with the same name as partial's name.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, it's not

```
<%= @article.user.'username' %>
```

but

```
<%= @article.user.username %>
```

Can you show a bit more of your controller where you are initializing @user?

Update: Based on more information given in the comment below. The error message was not on "User" but "user". As such the solution was to use the "article" object provided by the _article.html.erb partial (most probably invoked as a part of a render partial call from another view).

```
 <%= article.user.username %>
```

Comment: I think you formatted the error message a bit too much. Was it "undefined method `User' for nil:NilClass" or "undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass"? User is a class and user would be a method that cant be called on a non-existent @article.

Comment: Which means that @article is nil :) instead of @article instance variable, just drop the @ and try article which is same as the name of the partial and therefore might contain the actual "article" object.

Comment: You're right - removing the @ in article.user.username and @ in article.created worked. Thank you :-)